# Efficient way of using tikz when you're doing a lot of diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm going to do a big project on category theory / algebraic geometry and I need to use a lot of diagrams.

I'd like to now if there are some tricks to make it faster and easier. I assume that it's just a matter of practice but I'd like to know what people do usually in this situations.

Should I define a lot of commands with the most basic diagrams?

I hope this is not too subjective.

As an example of diagram:

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about which kind of diagrams? I think you have mainly two options: 1- Include tikz diagrams in your .tex file but just compile when necessary with `externalize` library. 2- Make your diagrams outside your document and include them with `includegraphics`. For this second option you can use `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` which allows to have all diagrams in one file but each one in its own page which can be used in `\includegraphics[page=x]{...}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I added a diagram which could represent well the kind of things I'll be doing. I hope it helps.

Comment: Use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). It has a pretty convenient syntax for commutative diagrams and you can use all the power of TikZ if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). This package is built upon TikZ and was designed specifically to draw commutative diagrams. It's very versatile, offers a lot of customization possibilities and it has a very concise and convenient syntax; besides, you have access to a wide variety of arrows (you have all the standard arrows usually found in those diagrams) and can use all the power of TikZ if required.

Here's a simple demonstration with the diagram in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{ker}
\newcommand\TwoMor[2]{
\mleft(\begin{smallmatrix}#1 \\ #2\end{smallmatrix}\mright)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm,column sep=1.5cm]
X
  \ar[dr,dotted,"w"]
  \ar[ddr,"v",swap]
  \ar[drr,"u"] 
& & &
\\
& 
\Ker\TwoMor{f}{g}
  \ar[r,dotted,"b'"] 
  \ar[d,dotted,"a'",swap] 
  \ar[dr,rightarrowtail,"k"] 
& 
B
  \ar[d,rightarrowtail,"b"] 
\\
& 
A
   \ar[r,"a",swap]
& 
C
  \ar[r,"f"] 
  \ar[d,"g",swap] 
  \ar[dr,"\TwoMor{f}{g}"] 
& 
D 
\\
& & 
E 
& 
D\times E
  \ar[u,"p_{D}",swap]
  \ar[l,"p_{E}"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of defining commands for diagrams themselves, as you suggested in your question, I'd rather define commands for elements that are often used in your diagrams; as an illustration, I defined `\TwoMor`:

```
\newcommand\TwoMor[2]{
\mleft(\begin{smallmatrix}#1 \\ #2\end{smallmatrix}\mright)
}
```

to quickly build a pair of morphisms.